# Add new property with default value to javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript

I want to add a new property to values called gender with a default value of "male". Is the only method to accomplish adding the property is to loop thru the array. Or is there a more efficient strategy?

```
var data = [];
data.push({id: 1, values: {"age":33,"name":"Duke"}});
data.push({id: 2, values: {"age":34,"name":"Dave"}});
var obj;
for obj in data {
  obj.values.gender = "male";
}
```

So the `data` will be

```
data = [
   {id: 1, values: {"age":33,"name":"Duke","gender":"male"}},
   {id: 2, values: {"age":34,"name":"Dave","gender":"male"}}
];
```

Comment: if you can't add a new property on array creation, to add it later you should loop. All other approaches are just variations

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in a loop.

Comment: @Kinduser he wants any alternate way.

Comment: If this can solve your problem. Then why you are looking for other possibilities?

Comment: @Ilyaskarim It can be done in dozens of variations, reduce, foreach, map etc, but the question is, for what? I guess the `for` loop has highest performance here.

Comment: @Ilyaskarim `for var obj in data` .. no errors?

Comment: @Tom oh yes there is a errror. He added it later.

Comment: `data.forEach(o => o.values.gender = 'male');`

Comment: @Ilyaskarim Added what later? When? There are no edits on the question (at this time)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I wonder if it would have better performance than `for in` loop. What do you think?

Comment: "A change has been made to post." And he added more code. I was the first visitor on this question.

Comment: @Kinduser, I think `forEach` should be the choice of all other variations. It would be enough for such simple case

Comment: If you make the objects from a prototype, you could add a prototype method that returns the default value of the new property if it doesn't exist in the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try OOP Javascript and use the prototype to add a property to all objects of that type:

```
function Person(age, name) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
}

var data = [];
data.push({id: 1, values: new Person(33, "Duke") });
data.push({id: 2, values: new Person(34, "Dave") });

Person.prototype.gender = 'male';

console.log(data[0].values.gender) // male
```

@Tom's answer is better if you know the property you want to add and it's not dynamic. My solution is better if the property you want to assign to all objects is unknown until runtime.

Comment: +1 for your answer, especially with the text underneath the code. I don't know who gave us `-1`s, but that person didn't care to explain why :(

Comment: Thanks (and likewise +1 for yours) - downvotes without explanations suck.

Comment: I down voted both - if I'm wrong I'll happily rescind but if you console.log(data) it does not produce what the OP wants imo - sorry for late reply, been checking it

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Fair enough, I see your point. I was assuming that they wanted to know how they could add a property to their objects without looping over each object. Though if you `console.log` the data you will not see the gender, if you are utilizing the resulting data structure in a loop or whatever and reference `item[i].values.gender` you will in fact get "male".

Comment: @RobM. I get you, but it's a bit dangerous to try and guess the users reason for their data structure - that was my only point mate

Comment: I'm 100% with you on that one, mate. Frequent occurrence on SO where I feel the need to guess user's reasons for their data structures and just try to pick out the general question. In this case: "Is the only method to accomplish adding the property..."

Comment: This was the kind of solution I was looking for to my question; add a property to an object in an existing array. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid to say you cannot avoid a for loop. However, I have created a comparison for you and you can think of the performance. As expected, a simple for loop is always faster. Take a look:

```js
var data = [];

data.push({id: 1, values: {"age":33,"name":"Duke"}});
data.push({id: 2, values: {"age":34,"name":"Dave"}});
data.push({id: 2, values: {"age":34,"name":"Dave"}});
data.push({id: 2, values: {"age":34,"name":"Dave"}});
data.push({id: 2, values: {"age":34,"name":"Dave"}});
data.push({id: 2, values: {"age":34,"name":"Dave"}});
data.push({id: 2, values: {"age":34,"name":"Dave"}});
data.push({id: 2, values: {"age":34,"name":"Dave"}});
data.push({id: 2, values: {"age":34,"name":"Dave"}});
data.push({id: 2, values: {"age":34,"name":"Dave"}});
data.push({id: 2, values: {"age":34,"name":"Dave"}});
data.push({id: 2, values: {"age":34,"name":"Dave"}});
data.push({id: 2, values: {"age":34,"name":"Dave"}});

function foreachFn(d){
 d.forEach(function(el){ el.values.gender='male'; });
  return d;
}


function simpleLoopFn(d){
  for (var i = 0;i<d.length;i++){
    d[i].values.gender = "male";
 }
}

function mappingData(d){
  let newdata = d.map(function(el)
  {
     el.values.gender = 'male';
  });
}


var t1 = 0, t2 =0;
let foreachData=data;
t1 = console.time('foreachFn')
foreachFn(foreachData);
t2 = console.timeEnd('foreachFn');

let simpleData= data;
t1 = console.time('simpleLoopFn')
simpleLoopFn(simpleData);
t2 = console.timeEnd('simpleLoopFn');

let mappedData = data;
t1 = console.time('mappingData')
mappingData(mappedData);
t2 = console.timeEnd('mappingData');
```

Comment: He asked alternative. It means no for loop in answer

Comment: @Ilyaskarim No, please read the question - it says nothing like that, at all!

Comment: I am afraid there is not. However, look at the comparison I made.

Comment: Comparison is v interesting actually - I've replicated it here https://jsperf.com/foreachloopspeedtest

Answer (score -1):

There is. You can work with objects and constructors to assign a default value to a property. Code speaks more than words:

```
var Person = (function () {
    function Person(age, name, gender) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender ? gender : "male";
    }

    return Person;
}());

var data = [];
data.push({ id: 1, values: new Person(33, "Duke") });
data.push({ id: 2, values: new Person(34, "Dave") });
```

Becomes:

```
data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        values: {
            "age": 33,
            "name": "Duke",
            "gender":"male"
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        values: {
            "age": 34,
            "name": "Dave",
            "gender":"male"
        }
    }
]
```

You might even do the following to change the gender other than male:

```
data.push({ id: 2, values: new Person(35, "Jessica", "female") });
```

jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wtomcskr/1/

Comment: If you `console.log(data)` it's nothing like the OPs desired result - unless I misread the question

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I just noticed gender is not inside the values I provided. Let me ajust this. Calling it 'nothing like it' seems a bit exaggerated.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I now see what you mean. I was more focused on the "more efficiënt" strategy. OP probably meant a more efficiënt strategy in combination with loops. If you don't like the (multiple) answers based on the question's formatting, maybe the question should have been asked in a different way, though.